# Django re-style form

Tags: python, django, forms

i currently try to "style" my form. in General i get the concept behind it but not at that point:

This is how it's intendet to be (and not working):

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'class-one-input-fields'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'class-one-input-fields'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'class-one-input-fields'}))
    pubpgp = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Public PGP Key', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'class-two-input-fields'}))
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        username = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        username.pubpgp = self.cleaned_data['pubpgp']

        if commit:
            username.save()

        return username
```

views.py:

```
def signup (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Thanks for you registration, you are now able to login.")
            return redirect(reverse('post_list'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', args)
```

The error i get is:

> AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped
>   for 'accounts.User'

in my settings.py i set:

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

This is the current working state:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    user = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'user',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'pubpgp'
        )

    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.pubpgp = self.cleaned_data['pubpgp']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

User model of accounts:

```
#User Model Manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, user, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not user:
            raise ValueError('Error: The User you want to create must have a username, try again')

        new_user = self.model(
            user=self.model.normalize_username(user)
        )

        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save(using=self._db)
        return new_user

    def create_staffuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given username and password.
        """
        new_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        new_user.staff = True
        new_user.save(using=self._db)
        return new_user

    def create_superuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        new_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        new_user.staff = True
        new_user.admin = True
        new_user.save(using=self._db)
        return new_user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    #User fields
    user = models.CharField(verbose_name='username',max_length=30,unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    pubpgp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = fields.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 350, 'max_height': 350}))
    ])

    #Account typs
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Username & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username ;)
        return self.user

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        """Is the user a admin member?"""
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        """Is the user active?"""
        return self.active

    objects = UserManager()
```

i guess that i have to pass the User model into this form somehow. Any idea about the syntax?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your `accounts.User`, can you share the (relevant parts of the) custom `User` model you have created?

Comment: What is the User that you reference in that Meta class? Is it auth.User or accounts.User?

Comment: accounts.User is my own user model here. I guess the "model = User" is simply missing, but no idea who to implement. Thanks in adavance

Comment: Did you create your user manager for your custom user model? Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

Comment: Yes i did and its working fine.

Comment: I first trought about that:
https://gist.github.com/markocalic1/99ab43a3d424c1b4d9da73d77985f7bd
but i only use "User" at my view and not even with the signup

Comment: somebody? any idea on this